# Woocommerce - Changing sender email address for Admin emails only

Tags: php, wordpress

Woocommerce sends a range of email notifications relating to customer activity.

The default 'From' sender email address is the same for Admin/system emails as well as emails the customer receives - The address is set from a single field.

[image: From address field]

Due to some spam issues, I need to set one From address for Admin emails, and another From address for customer emails.

How, if at all, can this be achieved?

Comment: You know wordpress.org. If you go to the plugin support page you can ask there for your request. It isn&#39;t avaliable till now so you can tell it to the plugin moderators, and they can release this option in the next version of woocommerce